# Init CodeCommit repository with seed-code stored in S3 using CDK

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit, aws-pipeline

I'm trying to convert the [MLOps template for model building, training, and deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-projects-templates-sm.html#sagemaker-projects-templates-code-commit) *CloudFormation* template into a CDK project so I can easily update the definitions, synth the template and upload it into *CloudCatalog* in order to be used as a project template in *SageMaker Studio*.

I'm quite new to CDK though, and I'm having some troubles trying to initialize a *CodeCommit* repository with the sagemaker pipeline `seed-code` stored in *S3*, which was accomplished as follows in the original template :

```yaml
  'ModelBuildCodeCommitRepository':
    'Type': 'AWS::CodeCommit::Repository'
    'Properties':
      'RepositoryName':
        'Fn::Sub': 'sagemaker-${SageMakerProjectName}-${SageMakerProjectId}-modelbuild'
      'RepositoryDescription':
        'Fn::Sub': 'SageMaker Model building workflow infrastructure as code for the
          Project ${SageMakerProjectName}'
      'Code':
        'S3':
          'Bucket': 'sagemaker-servicecatalog-seedcode-sa-east-1'
          'Key': 'toolchain/model-building-workflow-v1.0.zip'
        'BranchName': 'main'
```

The CDK API docs does refer to the `code` parameter in [codecommit.Repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codecommit.Repository.html#code) as an initialization option, but it's only for local files being compressed and uploaded to *S3* and such. That's because it assumes a deployment of the CDK project, but I only want the template generated by `cdk synth`.

Of course I can always use [codecommit.CfnRepository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codecommit.CfnRepository.html#code) and its `code` parameter to point into *S3*, but then I cannot insert it in the `codepipeline`'s stage [codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction.html)'s `repository` parameter because it expects an `IRepository` object.

I also want to stick to `aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline` to grasp the fundamental logic of *CloudPipeline* (which I'm quite new too) and avoid using the high level `aws-cdk-lib.pipelines`.

Any ideas on how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a `Repository` without a `Code` prop. Get an [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) reference to its L1 `CfnRepository` layer.  Set the `CfnRepository`'s property manually to the existing S3 bucket:

```js
const repo = new codecommit.Repository(this, 'Repo', { repositoryName: 'my-great-repo' });
const cfnRepo = repo.node.defaultChild as codecommit.CfnRepository;

cfnRepo.addPropertyOverride('Code', {
  S3: {
    Bucket: 'sagemaker-servicecatalog-seedcode-sa-east-1',
    Key: 'toolchain/model-building-workflow-v1.0.zip',
  },
  BranchName: 'main',
});
```

The above code will synth the YAML output in the OP.  Pass `repo` as the pipeline's source action.

Don't forget to grant the necessary IAM permissions on the S3 bucket.

Comment: That made the trick! Thank you so much!